# FluentNhibernate Cascading - Not Saved Parent Id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I have a problem with my fluent nhibernate.

My Codes,

BaseEntity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity<BaseEntity, int>, IDisposable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

IAuditInfo:

```
public interface IAuditInfo
{
    int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

ISeoFields:

```
public interface ISeoFields
{
    string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    string UrlAlias { get; set; }
}
```

Product Entity:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity, IAuditInfo
{
    #region "Constructors"

    public Product()
    {
        Translations = new List<ProductTranslation>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Properties"

    public virtual IList<ProductTranslation> Translations { get; set; }

    /******* Implemented from IAuditInfo *******/
    public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    /*******************************************/

    #endregion
}
```

ProductTranslation Entity:

```
public class ProductTranslation : BaseEntity, ISeoFields
{
    #region "Constructors"

    public ProductTranslation()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Properties"

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    /******* Implemented from ISeoFields *******/
    public virtual string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    public virtual string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string UrlAlias { get; set; }
    /*******************************************/

    #endregion
}
```

BaseMap:

```
public class BaseMap<TEntity, TIdentity> : ClassMap<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Id<TIdentity>("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    }
}
```

ProductMap:

```
public class ProductMap : BaseMap<Product, int>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.CreatedBy);
        Map(m => m.CreatedDate);
        Map(m => m.UpdatedBy);
        Map(m => m.UpdatedDate);

        HasMany<ProductTranslation>(x => x.Translations).KeyColumns.Add("ProductId").Cascade.All().Inverse();
        Table("Product");
    }
}
```

ProductTranslationMap:

```
public class ProductTranslationMap : BaseMap<ProductTranslation, int>
{
    public ProductTranslationMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.ShortName);
        Map(m => m.Description);
        Map(m => m.MetaKeywords);
        Map(m => m.MetaDescription);
        Map(m => m.MetaTitle);
        Map(m => m.UrlAlias);

        References<Language>(r => r.Language, "LanguageId");
        References<Product>(r => r.Product, "ProductId");

        Table("ProductTranslation");
    }
}
```

My Save Code:

```
var product = new Product();
product.CreatedBy = 1;
product.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
product.UpdatedBy = 1;
product.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
product.Translations = new List<ProductTranslation>() { 
    new ProductTranslation()
    {
        Name = "Sony Vaio Notebook",
        ShortName = "Sony Vaio Notebook Dizüstübilgisayar",
        Description = "Sony Vaio Notebook Dizüstübilgisayar, falan filan test açıklama",
        MetaDescription = "Meta Desc Sony Notebook Meta",
        MetaKeywords = "Sony,Notebook",
        MetaTitle = "Sony Computer",
        UrlAlias = "sony-Vaio-notebook",
        Language = new Language() {
            Culture ="tr-TR",
            CurrencyId =1,
            FlagImage="tr.png",
            Name="Turkish",
            Rtl = false
        }
    },
    new ProductTranslation()
    {
        Name = "ASUS N56VZ Notebook",
        ShortName = "ASUS N56VZ Notebook Dizüstübilgisayar",
        Description = "ASUS N56VZ Notebook Dizüstübilgisayar, falan filan test açıklama",
        MetaDescription = "Meta Desc Asus Notebook Meta",
        MetaKeywords = "ASUS,Notebook",
        MetaTitle = "ASUS Computer",
        UrlAlias = "asus-n56vz-notebook",
        Language = new Language() {
            Culture ="en-US",
            CurrencyId = 2,
            FlagImage="en.png",
            Name="English",
            Rtl = false
        }
    }
};

Repository.Save(product);
```

My Problem,

```
    ProductTable
    Id | CreatedBy | CreatedDate             | UpdatedBy  | UpdatedDate
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | 1         | 2015-03-19 12:42:31.000 | 1          | 2015-03-19 12:42:31.000

    LanguageTable
    Id | Name    | Culture  | FlagImage | Rtl | CurrencyId
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | Turkish | tr-TR    | tr.png    | 0   | 1
    2  | English | en-US    | en.png    | 0   | 2

    Id | Name                | ShortName            | Description          | MetaKeywords         |MetaDescription          | MetaTitle             | UrlAlias             | LanguageId  | ProductId
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    Sony Vaio Notebook  | Sony Vaio Notebook   | Dizüstübilgisayar    | Sony Vaio Notebook   |Dizüstübilgisayar, falan | filan test açıklama   | sony-Vaio-notebook   | 1           | NULL (Why Null, should be 1)
    2    ASUS N56VZ Notebook | ASUS N56VZ Notebook  | Dizüstübilgisayar    | ASUS N56VZ Notebook  |Dizüstübilgisayar, falan | filan test açıklama   | asus-n56vz-notebook  | 2           | NULL (Why Null, should be 1)
```

**As can be seen, LanguageId field was saved. But the ProductId was not saved in the ProductTranslation table.
Under normal conditions, ProductId field should be 1.**

***Please, help me. Where is my problem?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you just have to assign reference from collection to its item

```
var product = new SignECommerce.Domain.Entities.Product();
...
product.Translations = new List<ProductTranslation>();

// child (collection item) gets reference to parent
var item1 = new ProductTranslation()
{
   ...
    Product = product;
},
// now parent is known
var item2 = new ProductTranslation()
{
    ...
   Product = product;
}

// root of that all is now having children
product.Translations.Add(item1);
product.Translations.Add(item2);

// product save will cause all stuff to be properly persisted
Repository.Save(product);
```

And the reason why? We are using the **`.Inverse()`** mapping. That kind of mapping expects:

- that the item *(collection item)* will care about the persistance  and
- that such item must know about its parent *(collection holder)*

In general, with ORM/NHibernate we should always set bothe references. Parent to child and child to parent.

When data are loaded from DB, NHibernate will set that for us... During object(s) creation it is up to us